# bokeh plotting grouped dataframe as bar chart with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, bokeh, multi-index

I am struggling with making a bokeh plot that shows the result of a grouped dataframe. The following is the issue.

I have some data from a dataframe:

```
data = pd.read_csv('CompanyStructure.csv', index_col = 0)
```

which looks as the following and contains thousands more rows:

[image]

I would like to visualize this dataframe after grouping by thee variables. It could as well be a grouping of two or one variables. Below I have provided an example where I group across all of the three first columns:

```
grouped = data.groupby(by=['hour', 'Code', 'Type']).sum()
```

And the frame looks as following:

[image]

Now I would like to visualize this. The following is my approach:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=grouped)
p = figure(x_range = source.data['hour_Code_Type'].tolist())
p.vbar(x='hour_Code_Type', top='Value', source=source)
show(p)
```

Then I get the following error:

ValueError: Unrecognized range input: '[(0, 'DK1', 'A'), (0, 'DK1', 'P'), (0, 'DK1', 'T'), (0, 'DK2', 'A'), (0, 'DK2', 'P'), (0, 'DK2', 'T'), (1, 'DK1', 'A'), (1, 'DK1', 'P'), (1, 'DK1', 'T'), (1, 'DK2', 'A'), (1, 'DK2', 'P'), (1, 'DK2', 'T'), (2, 'DK1', 'A'), (2, 'DK1', 'P'), (2, 'DK1', 'T'), (2, 'DK2', 'A'), (2, 'DK2', 'P'), (2, 'DK2', 'T'), (3, 'DK1', 'A'), (3, 'DK1', 'P'), (3, 'DK1', 'T'), (3, 'DK2', 'A'), (3, 'DK2', 'P'), (3, 'DK2', 'T'), (4, 'DK1', 'A'), (4, 'DK1', 'P'), (4, 'DK1', 'T') ...

I do understand the error, but I simply cannot figure out how to solve this. How can I make the x_range visualize a value as the shown once. My ideal tool is an interactive one (hence why I am using bokeh), which will make a bar chart depending on which variables are choosen to group with.

I hope that someone can help me out.

Comment: Bokeh categorical factors are always strings, so as a first action all those ints in the tuples need to be converted to string, for certain.

Comment: @bigreddot thanx a lot for your contribution. Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue.

Comment: I didn't say it would, merely that that was one thing that was definitely wrong (possiby among others). Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to say more. If you had provided an MRE I would have run it and fixed it directly.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: As bigreddot pointed out, FactorRange could be used to avoid having string tuples as categoricals.

```
from bokeh.models import FactorRange

df['hour'] = df['hour'].astype(str) # To get Tuple(String, String, String) when grouping

grouped = df.groupby(by=['hour', 'Code', 'Type']).sum()
source = ColumnDataSource(data=grouped)

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*source.data['hour_Code_Type'].tolist()))
p.vbar(x='hour_Code_Type', top='Value', source=source)
show(p)
```

This renders

[image]

**Old answer:**

When you group on 'hour', 'Code' and 'Type' you are creating a MultiIndex. As you want categoricals in the x-range to be a list of strings, one approach could be to create a new column that converts the MultiIndex to a string.

```
grouped = df.groupby(by=['hour', 'code', 'type']).sum()
grouped['group'] = [''.join(str(x)) for x in grouped.index]
```

This gives this as the dataframe (using mock-data):

```
                value            group
hour code type
0    DK2  A       0.4  (0, 'DK2', 'A')
1    DK1  B       1.0  (1, 'DK1', 'B')
2    DK1  A       1.5  (2, 'DK1', 'A')
```

Then you could visualize value based on the 'group' column:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=grouped)

p = figure(x_range=source.data['group'].tolist())
p.vbar(x='group', top='value', source=grouped)
show(p)
```

To get:

[image]

Comment: Thanx @taul. So the trick is to create a new column identical to the multi index rather than using the multiindex it self?

Comment: Note that Bokeh can handle hierarchical (multi-part) factors and will render nested axes for them: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#mixed-factors It is not necessary to settle for the ugly tuple axis tick labels.

Comment: Thanks bigreddot, I edited my answer. Blindly forgot about FactorRange.